# Can os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] be set dynamically from within an application?

Tags: python

Can it be changed for the current process by simply setting it to a new value like this?

```
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = 'random'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends by what you mean.

If you mean to change the behaviour of the current interpreter than the answer is *no*:

1. Modifying `os.environ` isn't reliable, since in some OSes you cannot modify the environment (see the documentation for [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ)).
2. Environmental variables are checked only *when launching the interpreter*, so changing them afterwards will not have any effects for the current python instance. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables):

   > These environment variables influence Python’s behavior, *they are
   >   processed before the command-line switches other than `-E` or `-I`*.

   (which implies they are only checked when launching the interpreter, well before any user-code is run).

AFAIK, the random hash seed *cannot* be set dynamically, so you have to restart the interpreter if you want to activate hash randomization.

If you mean to make *new processes* spawned by the current interpreter behave as if that value was set before, then *yes*,  **assuming that you are running on a platform that supports `putenv`**. When spawning a new process, by default, it inherits the environment of the current process. You can test this using a simple script:

```
#check_environ.py
import os
import subprocess

os.environ['A'] = '1'
proc = subprocess.call(['python', '-c', 'import os;print(os.environ["A"])'])
```

Which yields:

```
$ python check_environ.py
1
```

Note that there exist known bugs in `putenv` implementations (e.g. in Mac OS X), where it leaks memory. So modifying the environment is something you want to avoid as much as possible.

Comment: With `subprocess.call`, you can work around modifying the environment by passing an explicit, augmented environment. `e = dict(os.environ); e.update(PYTHONHASHSEED='random'); subprocess.call([...], env=e)`

Comment: @chepner Yes, I well known that. It's clearly mentioned in the docs. I was answering a question about *modifying* the environment *of the current process*. In fact that part of the answer is a guess at what the OP may mean; if he edits his question clarifying what he means I'll add that suggestion (this was already in my thoughts when I first wrote the answer).