# OS environment variable reading in a spawned process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

This is similar to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684349/can-os-environpythonhashseed-be-set-dynamically-from-within-an-application) but for `multiprocessing` instead of `subprocess`. It seems that changing dynamically `PYTHONHASHSEED` has no effect when using `multiprocessing`, unlike `subprocess`:

```
#check_environ.py
import os, multiprocessing, subprocess, sys

s = 'hello'
print('parent', os.getenv('PYTHONHASHSEED'), hash(s))

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = sys.argv[1]
subprocess.call(['python', '-c', "import os;print('subprocess', os.getenv('PYTHONHASHSEED'), hash('{}'))".format(s)])
multiprocessing.Process(target=lambda:print('multiprocessing', os.getenv('PYTHONHASHSEED'), hash(s))).start()
```

Sample runs:

```
# explicit PYTHONHASHSEED for subprocess/multiprocessing 
$ python check_environ.py 12

parent None 4472558296122225349
subprocess 12 -8207222429063474615
multiprocessing 12 4472558296122225349

# random PYTHONHASHSEED for subprocess/multiprocessing 
$ python check_environ.py

parent None 7990499464460966677
subprocess None 1081030409066486350
multiprocessing None 7990499464460966677
```

So no matter what, the `multiprocessing` hash uses the same seed as the parent. Is there a way to force subprocesses spawned by `multiprocessing` use a different hash seed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, by using another start method than 'fork' for process creation. Your OS is using fork (you don't get a `PicklingError` for using a lambda as target).

You can change the start method to 'spawn' (default and only option on Windows) with `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` or to 'forkserver' if available. Get all available methods with `multiprocessing.get_all_start_methods()`.

```
#check_environ.py
import sys, os, subprocess
import multiprocessing as mp


def show(s):
    print('multiprocessing', os.getenv('PYTHONHASHSEED'), hash(s))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    mp.set_start_method('spawn')

    s = 'hello'
    print('parent', os.getenv('PYTHONHASHSEED'), hash(s))

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = sys.argv[1]

    cmd = "import os; " \
          "print('subprocess', os.getenv('PYTHONHASHSEED'), hash('{}'))"
    subprocess.call(['python', '-c', cmd.format(s)])
    p = mp.Process(target=show, args=(s,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Output in terminal:

```
$ python check_environ.py 12

parent None 4279361553958749032
subprocess 12 -8207222429063474615
multiprocessing 12 -8207222429063474615
```

If you need to switch between start methods multiple times use a context object for setting the start method:

```
ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
p = ctx.Process(target=foo, args=(var,))
```

But be prepared to pay a massive time penalty for using another start method than fork. I benchmarked just starting up a python process on my machine running Ubuntu 18.04 with:

- fork 1.59 ms
- forkserver 289.83 ms
- spawn 348.20 ms

But that doesn't have to be relevant for your use case.

Comment: Note: If you use a `multiprocessing.Pool`, rather than manually created `Process` objects, the penalty should be less; sure, it will still cost more to create the pool, but the worker processes are reused by many tasks, rather than one new spawned process per task.

Comment: Hi @Darkonaut, I have a question about running `multiprocessing.Pool` on Windows laptop [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66445724/why-does-this-parallel-process-run-infinitely-on-windows). I hope that you can take some time have a check on this question. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Each of the `python` processes is launched within a **new** OS environment whereas in the case of `multiprocessing` there is only **one**, shared, and inherited from the parent process.