# Packages that are imported are not recognized during parallel computing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, multiprocess

I'm running the function `get_content` in parallel setting with `multiprocess.Pool`. Then it throws out an error `NameError: name 'session' is not defined`. Clearly, I defined it with `session = requests.Session()` . Could you please elaborate on this issue?

```
import requests, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocess import Pool, freeze_support
core = os.cpu_count()
session = requests.Session() 
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

links = ['https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/0x-protocol.asp',
         'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/1-10net30.asp',
         'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/10-k.asp',
         'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/10k-wrap.asp',
         'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/10q.asp']

############ Get content of a word
def get_content(l):
    r = session.get(l, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    entry_name = soup.select_one('#article-heading_3-0').contents[0]
    main = soup.select('.comp.article-body.mntl-block')[0]
    content = entry_name + '\n' + '<link href="investopedia.css" rel="stylesheet"/>' + '\n' + str(main) + '\n</>\n'
    return(content)

############ Parallel computing
if __name__=="__main__":
    P = Pool(processes = core)   
    content_list = P.map(get_content, links)
    content_all = ''.join(content_list)    
    freeze_support()
```

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66460680/3220135) on your other question regarding how objects in the main process are shared with the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your import statement is incorrect and should be:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support
```

(You had `from multiprocess ...`, so I am not sure how it ran at all)

With the correct import statement, the code runs for me, but it does not what you think it does! I surmise by the call to `freeze_support` that you are running under Windows. Under that platform new processes are called by calls to system function `spawn`, which results in the entire program executing from the very top. This is why it becomes necessary for the code that creates the new processes to be within a block that is governed by `if __name__ == '__main__':`. If it weren't, then your newly created processes would be re-executing the code that just created them in a never-ending recursive loop spawning new processes forever.

This means that each process is re-creating its own `Session` instance due to the following statement being at global scope:

```py
session = requests.Session()
```

So you are getting no real benefit of being able to re-use the same `Session` instance for the multiple URLs you are attempting to retrieve. In order to reuse the same `Session` instance, you must initialize the multiprocessing pool itself with the session object so that it resides in shared memory and visible to all processes. You should also only keep the minimal executable code at global scope:

```py
import requests, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

def init_pool(s):
    global session
    session = s


############ Get content of a word
def get_content(l):
    r = session.get(l, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    entry_name = soup.select_one('#article-heading_3-0').contents[0]
    main = soup.select('.comp.article-body.mntl-block')[0]
    content = entry_name + '\n' + '<link href="investopedia.css" rel="stylesheet"/>' + '\n' + str(main) + '\n</>\n'
    return(content)

############ Parallel computing
if __name__=="__main__":
    core = os.cpu_count()
    session = requests.Session()

    links = ['https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/0x-protocol.asp',
             'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/1-10net30.asp',
             'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/10-k.asp',
             'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/10k-wrap.asp',
             'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/10q.asp']

    p = Pool(processes = core, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(session,))
    content_list = p.map(get_content, links)
    content_all = ''.join(content_list)
    print(content_all)
    freeze_support()
```

But in fact your code is mostly spending its time waiting for the URLs to be retrieved and just a little CPU time in processing the returned HTML. This is probably a good candidate for using multithreading instead of multiprocessing. The only changes you needed to your *original* code to use multithreading is (1) get rid of all references to `freeze_support` (which you did not need for multiprocessing unless you were planning on creating an exe file) and change one `import` statement:

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
```

Additionally, you should not be limited by the number of CPU cores you have in determining the number of threads to use (although there is some maximum you will not want to go over):

```py
import requests, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
session = requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

links = ['https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/0x-protocol.asp',
         'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/1-10net30.asp',
         'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/10-k.asp',
         'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/10k-wrap.asp',
         'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/10q.asp']

############ Get content of a word
def get_content(l):
    r = session.get(l, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    entry_name = soup.select_one('#article-heading_3-0').contents[0]
    main = soup.select('.comp.article-body.mntl-block')[0]
    content = entry_name + '\n' + '<link href="investopedia.css" rel="stylesheet"/>' + '\n' + str(main) + '\n</>\n'
    return(content)

############ Concurrent computing
if __name__=="__main__":
    # max of 25 is arbitrary; we do not want to appear to be a denial of service attack
    P = Pool(processes = min(len(links), 25))
    content_list = P.map(get_content, links)
    content_all = ''.join(content_list)
    print(content_all)
```

And, finally, you can combine both a thread pool and a multiprocessing pool using the latter to take care of the CPU-intensive portion of the processing:

```py
import requests, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
import os
from functools import partial


session = requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

links = ['https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/0x-protocol.asp',
         'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/1-10net30.asp',
         'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/10-k.asp',
         'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/10k-wrap.asp',
         'https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/10q.asp']

############ Get content of a word
def get_content(process_pool, l):
    r = session.get(l, headers = headers)
    return process_pool.apply(process_content, args=(r.content,))

def process_content(content):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    entry_name = soup.select_one('#article-heading_3-0').contents[0]
    main = soup.select('.comp.article-body.mntl-block')[0]
    content = entry_name + '\n' + '<link href="investopedia.css" rel="stylesheet"/>' + '\n' + str(main) + '\n</>\n'
    return(content)


############ Parallel computing
if __name__=="__main__":
    process_pool = Pool(processes = min(len(links), os.cpu_count()))
    thread_pool = ThreadPool(processes = min(len(links), 25))
    content_list = thread_pool.map(partial(get_content, process_pool), links)
    content_all = ''.join(content_list)
    print(content_all)
```

Comment: Now I get a feeling of complexity of parallel computing and understand why most games can not utilize the large number of CPUs inside a chip today. Thank you so much for your dedicated help!

Comment: I mean..... try the DOS first, then back down if you get banned for an hour ;)

Comment: I've added a third coding example that combines a thread pool with a multiprocessing pool just to show that it is possible.